# Keep-Alive functionality for include and exclude

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I want to exclude multiple components from my KeepAlive component.
I tried excluding multiple components but it only works for one single component.

```
<KeepAlive exclude="DetailView, NewClaim">
    <router-view v-if="isAuthenticated"></router-view>
</KeepAlive>

import NewClaimVue from "./views/NewClaim/NewClaim.vue";
import DetailViewVue from "./views/DetailView/DetailView.vue";
```

So here, my DetailView is getting excluded but not NewClaim component.

Comment: Give it a try with an array `[DetailView, NewClaim]`

Comment: I tried [DetailView, NewClaim] , but both the components are not working now. @kissu

Comment: Maybe forgot to have `:exclude`? Not sure if it's needed here but I guess so.

Comment: Still it shows the same. Isn't there any other to cache the current tabs without using 
Keep-Alive ? @kissu

Comment: Nope, there is not other way. Looking at [the example here](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html#include-exclude), the proper syntax looks like this: `:exclude="['DetailView', 'NewClaim']"` but you maybe want `include` here rather?

Comment: Can you please look into this issue ? @kissu
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028257/routing-issues-when-navigating-to-same-component/74028600?noredirect=1#comment130713079_74028600

Answer (score 1):

[Include / Exclude](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html#include-exclude)

> The match is checked against the component's name option, so
> components that need to be conditionally cached by KeepAlive must
> explicitly declare a name option.

[Name](https://vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#name)

> `interface ComponentOptions { name?: string }`

check your NewClaim and DetailView component name and use it as string.